# Given two sequences, find out whether its a subset or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Formally, a sequence is a special kind of function, a function is a special kind of a relation,
and a relation is a special kind of set. Thus, ultimately a sequence is some sort of a set. Given
two sequences, then, it makes perfect sense to ask whether one is a subset of the other. Is the
subset relationship between sequences (viewed as sets) the same as either the subsequence or
prefix relationship? In other words, suppose $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are arbitrary sequences over some set $A$.

$(a)$ Is it true that $\sigma \subseteq \tau$ if and only if $\sigma$ is a subsequence of $\tau$?

(b) Is it true that $\sigma \subseteq \tau$ if and only if $\sigma$ is a prefix of $\tau$?

Solution:

A sequence is defined as a function (First n elements of N) $\to$ alphabet

A function f: $A \to B$ is defined as a relation on A and B

A relation of A and B is the set $A \times B$

Therefore a sequence is the set of tuples (Natural number i, ith index element of the sequence).

Notice that the specific index of the element matters, this means that any subsequence that changes up the indices, will not be a subset as (new index, character) will not be the same as (original index, character). This is contrast with a prefix whose indices are the same, so it must be a subset.

---

Prefix definition from my textbook: The sequence $\sigma$ is a prefix of sequence $\tau$, if $(i) \sigma$ is finite and there is a sequence $\sigma'$ such that $\sigma \cdot \sigma' = \tau$, or $(ii) \sigma$ is infinite and $\sigma = \tau$. For example $(a, b, c)$ is a prefix of (a, b, c, d)

Comment: s is a subsequence of t iff range s is a subset of range t?

Comment: A sequence $\sigma$ is a subsequence of sequence $\tau$ if the elements of $\sigma$ appear in $\tau$ and do so in
the same order as in $\sigma$. For example, (b, c, f) is a subsequence of (a, b, c, d, e, f, g). Prefix would be: (a, b, c) is a prefix for (a, b, c, d)

Comment: Prefixes are subsets of sequences.  Subsets of sequences generally are not subsequences.